# Convert all the subsections of a JSON into columns of a DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I am trying to import and to convert a JSON into a DataFrame of Pandas. I am using the following code:

```
df=pd.read_json('df.json',typ='series')
df_2=pd.io.json.json_normalize(df)
```

But I have one problem, when I import the data I am obtaining some subsections  like a list and I need to separate everything in columns. I dont know why my code is only separating in one subsection like these:

```
entitities.xxxxx, people.xxxxx
```

I mean, when I import the JSON I am having:

```
|          entitites.hashtags            |
-----------------------------------------
|[{u'index':[0,13],u'text':u'Oh my God'} |
```

And I would like to obtain

```
|entities.hastags.index|entities.hashtags.text|  
-----------------------------------------------
|    [0,13]            | 'Oh my God'          |
```

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATED**

A part of my JSON could be for example:

```
{
  "text": "This is a nice test",
  "truncated": false,
  "entities":  {
    "hashtags":   [{"index": [62, 67], "text": "Mis5"}],
    "symbols":  [],
    "user_mentions":  [
       {
        "screen_name": "Name",
        "name": "Other name",
        "id": 9999999,
        "id_str": "771606164",
        "index":  [
          3,
          13
        ]
      }
    ],
    "urls":  []
  },
```

But not always the members have the same sucategories or nests

Comment: What does your json file look like?

Comment: Hi, I tried to answer your comment in the main post.